# jquery animate function begin time and how to set initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-animate, jquery-svg

I am using jquery.animate function for our line chart.

[image]

Animating both line and circle symbol. Please refer below code.

```
    _doLineAnimation: function() {
            var clipRect = $(this.chartObj.gSeriesEle).find("#" + this.gSeriesGroupEle.id + "_ClipRect").children();
            $(clipRect).animate(
                { width: parseFloat($(this.chartObj.gSeriesEle).find("#" + this.gSeriesGroupEle.id + "_ClipRect").children().attr("width")) },
                {
                    duration: 2000,

                    step: function(now) {
                        $(clipRect).attr("width", now);
                    }
                });

// the below code for animating the symbol
            var elements = $(this.chartObj.gSymbolGroupEle).children().not("defs");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var element = elements[i];
                this.animateSymbol(element);
            }

        }


animateSymbol:function(element) {
         var box = element.getBBox();
           var centerX = box.x + (box.width / 2);
           var centerY = box.y + (box.height / 2);
           var scaleVal;
               $(element).animate(
                   {
                       scale: 1,

                   },
                   {
                       duration: 2000,

                       step: function(now) {
                           scaleVal = now;
                           $(element).attr("transform", "translate(" + centerX + " " + centerY + ") scale(" + scaleVal + ") translate(" + (-centerX) + " " + (-centerY) + ")");


                       }
                   }
               );  
    },
```

My problem is tha both line and symbols are animating simultaneously. I want to perform the symbol animation(i.e. enlarge the symbol) whenever line reaches the point.

So I need to set some begin time for the symbol animation, now it  will start from 0 and ends after 2000 ms. But i need to  wait some time to animate each symbol after the line reaches each point.

I also need to set a start time in the animate() function, it will start from this time and ends after 2000ms.

I need to set some initial value as well in animate function.

ex: scale:1 means it will start from 0, but I want it to start from 0.5 to 1. How can I set the initial value in the animate() function ?

I need to set the begin time as well as to initialize the scale value at 0.5.

I'm expecting something like :

```
.animate ({
begintime: 1000

duartion:2000

initialvalue :scale :0.5
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) for delaying the start of the animation:

```
$(element).delay(1000).animate({}, 2000, function () {});
```

If delay doesn't work animate the element with a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(element).animate({}, 2000, function () {});
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i tried delay function  not working.it produce the same result.

Comment: @SivaRajini Updated with a 2nd suggestion.

Comment: i tried setTimeout too. not working.same output. animation occurs both line and symbol simultaneously.

Comment: @SivaRajini Then the issue is not that you do not delay the animation but that you trigger both animations simultaneously.